# Sliding Drawer hides last row of Fragment with GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, slidingdrawer

I want to have a sliding drawer underneath my gridview which is a fragment. I have two xml versions depending on screen size. Larger screens have two fragments side by side smaler screens have one fragment. Underneath the fragments i need to have the drawer but it hides the bottom elements of my grid. some pointers and help would be much appriciated.
this is what i get: 
[image: this is what i get]

I've already tried allsorts of variations, this is what i curently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
    </FrameLayout>
        <SlidingDrawer
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:content="@+id/content"
                android:handle="@+id/handle"
                android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:background="#000000">

                <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
                          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                          android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/handle"
                    android:src="@drawable/fav_stern" 
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second layout should basicly be the same only with a second fragment to the right of the first.

Comment: Be careful with SliderDrawer, as it has been deprecated as of API level 17.

Comment: swap your `RelativeLayout` for a `LinearLayout` with orientation `vertical` and see what happens

Comment: @Flynn81 thx, what would be an alternative with the exact same functionality?@Blundell thx also, i tried that at one point but that hid my gridview completly. Also read somewhere in the docs that you should use a realtive layou

Comment: As Blundell mentioned, you should change to LinearLayout. But also use Weights! Depending on the desired size of the slider (weight = 1), it would be good to give the framelayout a weigth between 5 and 10.

Comment: @Horschtele when i do that, i get i white field over my gridview in which the drawer itself slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset fragment's bottom by the height of the handler. One way would be to make the handler a consistent height and set the bottom margin.